# Tournament with three player teams and no repetitions

Tags: combinatorics

A friend of mine asked me for help with a problem. I'm trying to figure out if it has a solution or not.

We have 12 players, which will play 5 matches. Each player will play in all 5 matches.

Every match, the players will be divided into 4 teams of 3 players each. The idea is then that each player at some point will play in the same team as any other players - except one. The teams are not numbered.

Eg. P1 will play with [P2, P3, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9, P10, P11, P12], but not P4. 
The teams that P1 can play in might for example be:

(P1, P2, P3)
(P1, P5, P6)
(P1, P7, P8)
(P1, P9, P10)
(P1, P11, P12)

First, by symmetry we can say a few things:

1. We can define a match as a permutation of 1-12.
2. The first match can be [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12] without loss of generality.
3. Each team can be required to be described in numerical order, so (1,2,3) is a valid team but (2,1,3) is not.
4. The team order can be defined as min(team1) < min(team2), etc.

From this we can create a basic pattern:

[1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9 | 10 11 12]

[1 _ _ | 2 _ _ | 3 _ _ | _  _  _]

[1 _ _ | 2 _ _ | 3 _ _ | _  _  _]

[1 _ _ | 2 _ _ | 3 _ _ | _  _  _]

[1 _ _ | 2 _ _ | 3 _ _ | _  _  _]

I've come up with three different strategies to solving this.

A:
Begin by deciding the pairs that never can meet, and try to add to this list for each new match.

B:
Begin by deciding all the pairs that can meet and remove from that for each new match.

C: 
Decide how the team containing player 1 should look for each match and work from there.

I tried all options and while nice and symmetric, A and B didn't lead me anywhere.
I then attempted to solve using option C by brute force in Prolog, but while I get quite a few results for the first 4 matches, it says it can't find any solution when I add the last.

I don't trust my prolog skills enough, so my question is simply: Is there a solution to this problem, and if so, what is it?